# ASP.NET reaching localhost from mobile device results in "Connection Reset"

Tags: asp.net, mobile, localhost

I have a ASP.NET app running on my pc localhost on port 44329. The pc is on a WIFI network that my mobile phone is on too. I added a inbound rule in the firewall to allow connections to this port.

When I now go to the ip of my pc with the port it now doesn't get blocked anymore by the firewall, but in the browsers on my phone I still see a 400 error with "Invalid Hostname".
The ASP.NET app is running from Visual Studio in IIS Express.

Does anyone know why this happens and how I can fix this?

I can't use tunneling software for security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

I remember I had this problem a couple of years ago. Not sure how I solved it but i think it had something to do with IIS express, which has a binding to localhost and not to the ip adress of your computer.
So maybe not an answer but something to check

I just checked on my pc for the location of the config. You can set the binding in applicationhost.config inside .../MyDocuments/IISExpress/config and do a search on "localhost". You should be able to add a binding

EDIT: I don't have the settings. It was years ago and i reinstalled since then.

But something got me thinking. Different applications run on different ports so it can't be in the IIS folder. So I went looking and i found the IIS config in the project folder. In my case

```
C:\Users\info\source\repos\project-name\.vs\project-name\config
```

.vs is a hidden folder

But in your custom config you put the port number behind the ip adress. When you look at the default line, the port number is before the ip adress

ANOTHER EDIT: just tried it myself and I got it working. Open launchsettings.json in visual studio and change one of the profiles. In my case I changed **localhost into 0.0.0.0** in this one:
[image]

And now i can reach my project on http://192.168.1.10:5115

So forget all the previous stuff. It's pretty simple ;-)

Comment: I tried this in my applicationhost.config. The ip is the local ip of my laptop on the wifi and the port is the port the asp.net app runs on. I get invalid host regardless whether the iisexpress is running or not.

What bindings do you have in you host? What is the format of ip-port etc.?

    <bindings>
     <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation=":8080:localhost" />
     <binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="10.0.4.96:44329" />
    </bindings>

Comment: I tried putting the bindings in the applicationhost.config like you mentioned, but I still get invalid host name both on my phone and pc when I enter the ip and port (both for http and https which have different ports.

                <bindings>
                    <binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:44329:10.0.4.96" />
                    <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:63650:10.0.4.96" />
                </bindings>

Comment: It is a real pain to get IIS express to work. You often have to edit the config file for IIS, and not your project settings. However, before you do more hunting and fishing? I would delete the "site.mobile.master"  page if one exists.